# Can "ˈproʊɡræm(program)" be pronounced "ˈproʊɡrəm"?

Tags: pronunciation

I learned unstressed vowel sounds sound "ə".

So, I think "proʊɡræm" can sound "proʊɡrəm" because æ is not a stressed vowel sound in the word.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that *program* can be pronounced as /proʊɡrəm/. But your guess is based on two somewhat questionable premises.

> I learned unstressed vowel sounds sound "ə".

Vowels in fully unstressed syllables tend to be reduced to /ə/, but not always. One common counterexample is words ending in /i/, like the word *happy*: the last syllable is unstressed, but its vowel is usually not pronounced as /ə/. (To be more specific: there are some dialects where reducing word-final /i/ to /ə/ is more common, but it's not usual in the accents of English that are commonly taught to learners.) When it's usual to reduce a vowel to /ə/, you can usually find that pronunciation given explicitly by a good dictionary. I wouldn't recommend trying to use /ə/ in your pronunciation in syllables that your dictionary only transcribes with another vowel.

I wrote an answer to a question on ELU that has some more information on vowel reduction that might be helpful: [Orthograpy of /æ/ in unstressed syllables](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/489499/orthograpy-of-%C3%A6-in-unstressed-syllables)

> I think "proʊɡræm" can sound "proʊɡrəm" because æ is not a stressed vowel sound in the word

In fact, the pronunciation with of *program* with /æ/ in the second syllable is often analyzed as having a minor stress on that syllable. For the purposes of vowel reduction, an English word doesn't necessarily have just one stressed syllable. Secondary or tertiary stress (marked in transcriptions with a low stress mark before the syllable: `ˌ`) will prevent a vowel from being reduced to /ə/, even if the vowel is not is the primary-stressed syllable (marked in transcriptions with the high stress mark: `ˈ`).

British dictionaries tend not to transcribe minor stresses on syllables to the right of the syllable with primary stress, but American dictionaries often do. The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=program) gives two pronunciations for *program*:  translated into IPA, they are /ˈproʊˌɡræm/ and /ˈproʊɡrəm/. The vowel in the second syllable can be reduced to schwa when it is fully unstressed—but it can also be unreduced, with minor stress on the syllable (in addition to the major stress on the first syllable of the word).

There is no rule of English pronunciation that rules out either of these pronunciations: for each word like this, you have to learn whether it is pronounced with a reduced vowel or an unreduced vowel (or whether both pronunciation are used, as with the word *program*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the word is not emphasised in the sentence then unstressed vowels tend to become [ə] especially if you is speaking quickly.  When speaking slowly or carefully the vowel would be enunciated as [æ].  I think American dialects tend to make /æ/ with an even lower tongue than RP, so American dialects would tend not to use a [ə] as often as RP accents.